# EntityFrameworkCore .net Core update existing database structure without deleting existing data

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to update existing database structure without deleting existing data in .net core?
it was working in .net EF6 but not in this version
am i missing something?

All I have is

namespace ProjectTemplate.Contexts
{
    public class Dummy
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string firstName { get; set; } 

    public int age { get; set; }
    public string otherfield { get; set; }

    public string anotherField { get; set; }

}
```

}

and added one more property         public string one { get; set; }

then it delete the entire database and create a new one :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)?

In the package manager console run:

```
add-migration NameOfYourMigration
```

Then:

```
Update-Database
```

Or if you prefer to use the CLI:

```
dotnet ef migrations add NameOfYourMigration
```

Then:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: Sorry i mean programatically when the structure is changed. we were able to do in the EF 6,